# Birthdays in SQL... disregard year in a date value

Tags: sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I want my winforms display birthdays on that date, however I'm not sure how to compare the present date and a datetime format. For example, if my birthday was 1/1/1990, I want my datagrid to show my info on 1/1/2011. I'm not sure how to parse the date in SQL; if anyone can help me that would be great!

Comment: please refer to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394947/sql-query-working-only-at-times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should give you a good idea:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Users
WHERE
   MONTH( Users.Birthdate ) = MONTH( GetDate() )
   AND
   DAY( Users.Birthdate ) = DAY( GetDate() )
```

Comment: +1.  I had a clever answer using JulianDate vie datepart(dayofyear...) but it crahsed and burned over leap year. Make sure your final solution takes that into account!

Answer (score 1):

Another way similar to the first.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE
 DatePart(d, Users.Birthdate) = DatePart(d, GetDate() )
 AND
 DatePart(m, Users.Birthdate ) = DatePart(m, GetDate() )
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using Jamie F's example.  Potentially more index friendly, you'd have to try it and see though.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Users
WHERE
  DATEADD(YEAR, -DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Users.Birthdate), Users.Birthdate)
  =
  DATEADD(YEAR, -DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GetDate()      ), GetDate()      )
```