# sql query working only at times

Tags: sql

i need your help on this
i need to pull birthdays between two dates irrespective of year
i use the below query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM family_member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') order by MONTH(dob), DAYOFMONTH(dob)";
```

the query works well if i give the
- start date as Nov 6 &
- End date as Dec 13

but the query returns zero records if i give
- start date as Sept 6 &
- end date as Dec 13

it works at certain scenarios. can you please let me know the issue i need to correct

Comment: can you put in the data of the family_member table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact, that September is the 9th month and "09" and "9" are not the same string. Use `%m` instead of `%c`

**Edit**

Some explanation as requested: For the month range of September to December your comparison range was `9-06` to `12-06`. Now remembering, that this is a **string** comparison, e.g. `10-25` is NOT bigger than `9-06`, meaning the `BETWEEN` clause will produce no meaningful results. If you chose 2-digit months, you end up comparing `09-06` to `10-25`, which works as expected.

Comment: thanks, this worked... but can you please help me understand the difference between %m and %c... thanks!

Comment: %m-Month, numeric (00-12). as 09 is falling in between this range he used this

Comment: For January, %c="1" and %m="01".